# Rooting and updating to Official Updates

Tags: rooting, updates, samsung-galaxy-s-2

I have a S2. I want to root my phone to use the amazing apps out there Not to install custom roms. Can i still get access to the official updates from Samsung ?

Answer (score 4):

I recommend using [OTA RootKeeper](https://market.android.com/details?id=org.projectvoodoo.otarootkeeper). From the app description:

> This application makes a backup or a protected backup of your device's root.
>   This device must already be rooted: OTA RootKeeper doesn't have the ability to root devices.

It allows you to temporary un-root your phone for OTA updates and then restore back root.

Before installing please check [this XDA thread](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1241517).