# Galaxy S2 - Accessing Internal phone memory in Recovery Mode

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2, adb, recovery-mode, mount

How can i access to Internal Storage in Recovery mode using Android Debug Bridge (ADB.exe) ?

```
C:\Users\MohammadReza\Desktop\platform-tools>adb devices
List of devices attached
4F58000600000001        recovery

C:\Users\MohammadReza\Desktop\platform-tools>adb remount
remount failed: Operation not permitted

C:\Users\MohammadReza\Desktop\platform-tools>adb shell
$ mount /system
mount /system
Usage: mount [-r] [-w] [-o options] [-t type] device directory
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot issue `adb remount` unless your handset is rooted, which is why it failed in your case a la "remount failed: Operation not permitted".

There is an [answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/19766/rooting-and-updating-to-official-updates) to how to root the Galaxy S2.

Comment: My phone is locked due to too many pattern attempts, can i root my phone in recovery mode ?

Comment: In that case, there should be a button on that lock screen with "Forgot pattern?", tap that, and enter your google account details to sign in.

Comment: Unfortunately i don't remember the Google Id. the only option left for fixing my phone is "Hard reset", but i need some of my files.

Comment: too bad, a hard reset will have to do!

Comment: Bad  News : I performed the Hard Reset!
Good News : I have my files back! :)

Comment: YAY! \o/ :D Glad to hear that :)

Answer (score -2):

i don't know much about the Android debug bridge, but i guess hard reset (simple) can do the trick for you. i have a solution with me right now, actually i had some sort of issues on my GS2, so i bookmarked the forum where i had found the solution, here it have a look:- http://howmobile.net/samsung/2150-how-hard-reset-samsung-galaxy-s2.html it worked like a charm for me and i hope will do the same for you and other who are looking for a Galaxy S2 hard reset procedure. thanx

Comment: Don't make someone visit another site to get the information they need. When that link stops working this "answer" is absolutely worthless.